# -moz-linear-gradient

Tags: css

Could someone explain to me what this portion of code means?

```
repeat scroll 0 0 #F6F6F6;
```

I have googled a lot and only found syntax to this part

```
-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF, #EFEFEF)
```

My code:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF, #EFEFEF) repeat scroll 0 0 #F6F6F6;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are actually part of the [`background` CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp), not `-moz-linear-gradient`. Have a look at that link, it should explain.

Basically:

- `repeat`: The background repeats!
- `scroll`: When the page scrolls, the background scrolls too
- `0 0`: Says, "start the background from this point in the image".

All the extra stuff is probably unneccessary - they seem to be the same as the defaults.

Comment: No problem. I find the combined CSS properties (`background`, `border`, etc.) confusing myself - I prefer to use `background-image`, `background-repeat`, etc. separately.

Answer (score 0):

`background: <image> <repetition> [scroll] <pos-x> <pos-y> <color>;`

- image can be both an image url() or in some browsers, a gradient object.
- repetition can be no-repeat, repeat-x, repeat-y or repeat (both) and means how to repeat the image if it doesn't fill the background.
- if scroll is set, the background will stay fixed on the screen and not follow the text when you scroll.
- pos-x and pos-y determines the offset of the background.
- color means the color that used if the image value was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Those are additional options to the `background:` css shorthand.

The `repeat` repeats the image (although, -moz-linear-gradient doesn't support repeating).

`scroll` (as opposed to `fixed`) allows the background to "scroll"

`0 0` are x and y coords for the placement of the top left corner of the image.

`#F6F6F6 is a background color`